# Combinadics for combinations with certain elements

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of combinations $\binom mn$, I want to find out the [combinadics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) of all the combinations where $x$ and $y$ are present.

Let me explain myself with an example. Consider all the 15 combinations of (0,1,2,3,4,5) elements taken 4 at at time:

{0,1,2,3}, 
{0,1,2,4},
{0,1,2,5},
{0,1,3,4}, 
{0,1,3,5},
{0,1,4,5}, 
{0,2,3,4},
{0,2,3,5},
{0,2,4,5},
{0,3,4,5},
{1,2,3,4},
{1,2,3,5}, 
{1,2,4,5},
{1,3,4,5}, 
{2,3,4,5}

I want to find the combinadic of the combinations which contain a 2 and a 4. The solution in this case would be [2,7,9,11,13,15).

How could I do it without brute forcing it?